# How to make a UL the same size as its cousin?

Tags: html, css

I have this structure:

```css
#container {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
section {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#section1 {
  background: blue;
}
#section2 {
  background: cadetblue;
}
ul {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id='section1'>My list
    <ul id='list1'>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section id='section2'>My other list
    <ul id='list2'>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

I want both of the ULs to be the same height without using JS. I assume I'd have to get the `section` divs to match then make the ULs 100% height of their parents. I am not able to figure this out. I tried [this](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) article, but I must be missing something.

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/011gaa3w/

Comment: I am not sure if my recent blog post would help, but here you go. http://blog.dnwebdev.com/index.php/2015/07/29/my-bootstrap-tool-belt-equal-height-columns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flexbox` can do that with the existing structure very simply.

```css
#container {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#section1 {
  background: blue;
}
#section2 {
  background: cadetblue;
}
ul {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id='section1'>My list
    <ul id='list1'>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section id='section2'>My other list
    <ul id='list2'>
      <li>something</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` like in this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rc3cfgo5/

Comment: could you reproduce the same with the current structure?

Comment: I will end up doing this (adding a new outer div), but I'd like to see if you can do it with the current structure.

Comment: That almost works! the ULs are different heights though. http://jsfiddle.net/qnakqne3/

Comment: what you mean with they are different heights?

Comment: See the fiddle in my comment. The oranges should be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Create a CSS class to both lists -

```
.fixed-height {
    min-height: 6.0em;
}
```

And add it to both uls

```
<div id="container">
<section id='section1'>My list
    <ul id='list1' class="fixed-height">
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something</li>
    </ul>
</section>
<section id='section2'>My other list
    <ul id='list2' class="fixed-height">
        <li>something</li>
    </ul>
</section>
</div>
```